Layout Issues in Lightning Experience (Working Fine in Salesforce Classic)
I'm encountering a layout issue in Salesforce Lightning Experience that does not exist in Salesforce Classic. In Salesforce Classic, the page layout displays correctly, with all fields and columns aligned properly. However, when viewing the same page in Lightning Experience, the layout is messed up. Specifically, fields and columns are misaligned, and some data appears misplaced.
Lightning:

Classic:

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve this layout problem in Lightning Experience?
